# CSS float IE9 x Chrome

Tags: css

I am able to show it ok in IE9, but in Chrome the number goes down. Trying to fix this for Chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/we17rtoc/

[image]

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>AAAA</th>
            <th>AAAA</th>
            <th>AAAA</th>
            <th>AAAA</th>
            <th>AAAA</th>
            <th>AAAA</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" style="padding-top: 5px; width: 25px;"><span class="label label-success" style="margin-bottom: 3px; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 22px; padding-top: 2px;"><i class='fa fa-check' style="font-size: 18px;"></i></span><span style='position: relative; top: -15px; right: 0px; left: 21px;'><span style='text-align: center; float: left; width: 22px; height: 22px; border: 2px solid #5cb85c; border-radius: 100%; background-color: #f0ad4e; color: white;'>6</span></td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for any info.

Comment: At least externalise that inline CSS won't you...it's hard enough as it is.

Comment: I will. thanks, this is just for testing : )

Comment: Maybe so but if you want our help,,,make it easy for us...put that CSS in the CSS block of the JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `float` and set `display: inline-block` to the span containing a number.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/we17rtoc/4/